# Add link to field of view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view

I have put one view on my application page.

I like to add link for one field of view. These are the field of view, in which I want to add link for titleAbc field.

```
<ViewFields>
            <FieldRef Name="titleAbc"/>
            <FieldRef Name="avbc"/>
            <FieldRef Name="pqr"/>
        </ViewFields>
```

How to create link for titleAbc field in view and how to give dynamic url in that?

Comment: Is this a client side code or server side ? where is the link ?

Comment: any one which is you know

Answer (score 1):

Add below javascript on the page. "MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2" is the ID of listview wepart div. And I'm assuming titleAbc is the 4th column. This will work and you can modify script as per your requirement.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {        
                var titleAbc = "";
                $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2 table tr .ms-itmhover').each(function () {
                    titleAbc = $(this).find("td:nth-child(4)").text();
                   $(this).find("td:nth-child(4)").empty().append("<a href='http://www.google.com'>" + titleAbc + "</a>");        
                });    
            });   
        </script>
```

A second approach to solve this is create a calculated column of numeric type and add below formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("<DIV><a href='http://www.google.com'>",titleAbc,"</a></DIV>
```

Comment: Is there any other way like xsl:value-of. pls refer this link: http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-designer-help/add-a-hyperlink-to-a-data-view-HA010240364.aspx

Comment: I have tried but not working in which above link steps are there

Comment: Anyone know that how to add link in view in sharepoint 2013? I will not found any solution for sharepoint 2013.